# Run a do loop from a high iterator value to lower

Tags: procedural-programming

I wanna have a do loop that runs from the a high number to a smaller one. That is, if we have

```
Do[Print[n],{n,1,4}]
```

I would get 1,2,3,4 in the output. I rather wanna have 4,3,2,1. That is, morally I want to implement

```
Do[Print[n],{n,4,1}]
```

which doesn't work. How is this implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Do[Print[n], {n, 4, 1, -1}]
(* 4,3,2,1 *)
```